# Socket.io broadcast to namespaces in client side

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, namespaces

I have two namespaces which i created on the server side. The root namespace and a GroupChatEvents namespace.

In the client, I want to broadcast a message to both namespaces. Is that possible?

Client side code

```
var socket = io();
var GroupChatEventsSocket = io('/GroupChatEvents');
```

GroupChatEventsSocket.emit and socket.emit both only send to their specific namespaces. How can I broadcast to multiple specific namespaces?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no ability to broadcast directly to a namespace from the client.  Instead, you can create a message that you send to the server that tells the server which namespaces you want to broadcast to and then create a listener for that message on the server that will do it.  Remember, there are no client-to-client connections in webSocket/socket.io.  All connections are client to server.

So, if you want something sent to another client, you have to ask the server to do it for you.  This is true whether sending to a single client or broadcasting to all clients connected to a particular namespace.

> How can I broadcast to multiple specific namespaces?

Create a message you can send to the server that specifies the message content and the list of namespaces you want it sent to.  Then, implement a listener for that message on the server and when it receives that it can take the desired message and send it to each of the desired namespaces.

Just remember that unless you have some sort of authentication for who is allowed to do this that anyone might be able to connect to your server and do this type of broadcast.